# How to implement a Horizontal scrollable UI control in Samsung Bada

Tags: scroll, gallery, bada

We have started working on samsung bada platform for our existing android apps and looking for a UI Control in samsung bada platform which is horizontally scrollable like we have Gallery control in Android.

I need to show a set of image thumbnails in a container which is scrollable in left to right direction. Each image should be able to listen click on it .

What is the right way to implement such custom control ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below link might help., there is a sample also

http://developer.bada.com/article/Horizontal-Scroll-Panel